# Database and Data Framework

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas

I am interesting in building databases and have been reading about `SQL` engines and `Pandas` framework, and how they interact, but am still confused about the difference between a `database` and a `data framework`.

I wonder if somebody could point me to links which clarify the distinction between them, and which is the best starting point for a `data analysis` project.

Comment: The database is where you store the data. The data framework is what `tools` you use (code someone else wrote, but you only run, not develop)  to find structure in the data or other information/insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database is place where you store data collection. You can manipulate data by DML statement and some statements can be more difficult (like pivots or functions). Data framework is tool to make your computations, pivots and other manipulating much more easier (for example with drag and drop option).